# Search Force.com IDE by Namespace Prefix

Tags: managed-package, search

How can you use the eclipse file search in order to return all files that contain a string within a Namespace Prefix?

[image: Search Box]

Need the results for files with components that contain 'MagicApps' in the Namespace Prefix but not necessarily 'Unicorn'

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `Unicorn` and use `MagicApps_`.

If you are looking for it to be the start of the string, check `Regular Expression` and prepend `\A` to your [regex](http://rubular.com/r/YxzVupl8g5): `\AMagicApps_`.

Comment: It will return files where the field api names contain MagicApps_. Is it possible to isolate this to the namespace prefix?